# Non-Sharepoint metadata being imported to Sharepoint

Tags: metadata, import

We're going to be implementing SharePoint some time next year.  However, in the shorter term people will be going through and organizing current docs and images, and I'm trying to see if there's any tagging they can do during that process so that we can import into SharePoint later.

There are two scenarios, here - for docs we'd like to add keyword and other metadata just through Windows or similar, and for images we'd like to add tags through Adobe Bridge or similar.  Are there ways we can accomplish either task that won't be wasted work when we go to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Office products have the capability to create and populate metadata. On the File tab, select Info. On the right side, click the properties dropdown. You can display the document panel and create new properties from here. When you eventually create your libraries, you'll have to create columns to match.

Comment: These seem to be the same tags that show up when you just right-click on the file and go to details, correct? (When I added one from within the file it showed up in Windows Explorer, and vice versa.)  Those import with the file?  I tried both and couldn't see the data anywhere after I brought them into SharePoint.  Maybe the problem is just that I don't have the right thing enabled in SP to match it...I assumed that even without setting up columns I'd see any metadata in the file properties in SP, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll poke at the column issue more, then, and go from there

Comment: You have to set up the columns in SharePoint first.

Comment: Hmmm...I made a custom property in a Word file and added some text.  Then I made a site column with the same name, and added it to my library and my default view.  Uploaded the Word file - the custom property did not automatically map, and I didn't get any option during upload to manually map.  Am I missing a step?  Also, I'm not sure these custom properties will be useful to us in most scenarios, since they're pretty hidden from the average user, but there's a couple of things we're going to be scripting where maybe we can use these.